Can i use custom component variable in slot in laravel
I want to use custom component as described below(want to access variables in slot so i can use them without reapeatation)
    <x-Vector::admin.field label="Page Title" fname="page_title">
        <input type="text" name="{{$label}}" id="{{$label}}" placeholder="{{$fname}}">
    </x-Vector::admin.field>

I want to use label and fname variable in slot.

No clue where you have the slot and where not, but if you place a call to xdebug_break() into the blade template, you can inspect the variable table easily with the step debugger.
